# passing data from a windows form to a xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm using WPF for creating my application, I am calling a windows form using formobject.Show() 
from a xaml.cs file,

In the form I have Accept button and a cancel button . How to make the xaml.cs file know which button is clicked by the user in the form.? As the Execution(in ###.xaml.cs) depends on the button clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, used the property

`this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` in the the form

and used

`if (confirm.DialogResult.ToString() == "OK")` in the cs file to check which button is clicked

@Sebastian thanks for the idea.

Comment: You can Also compare (confirm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK). Here's a list of possible values : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do pure Confirm / Cancel evaluation or do you want to evaluate a more complex result? For cancel / confirm, you can do as described [here](http://www.itjungles.com/dotnet/how-to-easily-apply-acceptbutton-and-cancelbutton-for-custom-dialog-box-in-winform), using AcceptButton and CancelButton (those are for convenience only, to hook up Esc and Enter with the buttons) and the DialogResult property.

A more complex result is done just the same way, just that you don't set the DialogResult, but a custom property:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyProperty = "Some complex result";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyProperty = "Some other complex result";
    }
}
```

You can easily use `myWinform.MyProperty` to get the value in your XAML.cs file once the modal dialog is closed (the instance is not disposed, since your variable references it).